# Making Redis sets for fast lookup

Tags: sql, nosql, redis, dataset

I have query to find counts out of the table,

```
SELECT count(1) from table where 
  c1 in (1,2,3) 
  and c2 in (6,7,8)
  -- and c1 != c2
```

Now, I would like to do same thing but using Redis (possibly [sets](http://redis.io/commands#set)?).

How these sets should look like, and what operations should be performed to get result?

Comment: Your last condition seems reduntant to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alexander yes, it looks it is.

Comment: Didn't get your example. Can you change the example query a bit?

Comment: @Manu the query will count only these rows where `table.c1` is either `1,2 or 3` AND where `table.c2` is either `6,7 or 8`

Comment: Seems that redis's intersection and union commands could help you. You can find them in set's or zset's commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [`SINTER`](http://redis.io/commands/sinter) is what you are looking for.